# Runtime error : Segmentation fault with libtommath and libtomcrypt

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking, libtool

I am trying to run sample rsa/dsa code using libtomcrypt.

I have installed LibTomMath first as **make install**, as a result following files are created.

`/usr/lib/libtommath.a 
/usr/include/tommath.h`

After that I installed libtomcrypt with  LibTomMath as external library

```
CFLAGS="-DLTM_DESC -DUSE_LTM -I/usr/include" EXTRALIBS="/usr/lib/libtommath.a " make install
```

As a result following file is created

```
/usr/lib/libtomcrypt.a
```

I am not getting any error while running following command

```
CFLAGS="-DLTM_DESC -DUSE_LTM -I/usr/include" EXTRALIBS="/usr/lib/libtommath.a " make test
```

I have gone through this document [libtomcrypt_installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783079/unable-to-link-tomsfastmath-into-libtomcrypt) and [libtomcrypt_resolved](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libtom/uuP0kqF2LbY) to successfully compile using

```
gcc -DLTM_DESC rsa_make_key_example.c -o rsa -ltomcrypt 
or
gcc rsa_make_key_example.c -o rsa -ltomcrypt
```

**no compile error**. **However when I try to run, I got following error.**

```
 ./rsa

 LTC_ARGCHK 'ltc_mp.name != NULL' failure on line 34 of file src/pk/rsa/rsa_make_key.c
 Aborted
```

**Here is my sample rsa code**

```
#include <tomcrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

# ifdef USE_LTM
ltc_mp = ltm_desc;
# elif defined (USE_TFM)
ltc_mp = tfm_desc;
# endif 


    rsa_key key;

    int      err;
    register_prng(&sprng_desc);

    if ((err = rsa_make_key(NULL, find_prng("sprng"), 1024/8, 65537,&key)) != CRYPT_OK) {
        printf("make_key error: %s\n", error_to_string(err));
        return -1;
    }
    /* use the key ... */
    return 0;

}
```

**Here is my sample dsa code**

```
#include <tomcrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

# ifdef USE_LTM
ltc_mp = ltm_desc;
# elif defined (USE_TFM)
ltc_mp = tfm_desc;
# endif 


    int      err;
    register_prng(&sprng_desc);

    dsa_key key;


    if ((err = dsa_make_key(NULL, find_prng("sprng"), 20, 128,&key)) != CRYPT_OK) {
        printf("make_key error: %s\n", error_to_string(err));
        return -1;
    }
    /* use the key ... */
    return 0;

}
```

Here is how I have compiled it successfully,

```
gcc dsa_make_key_example.c -o dsa -ltomcrypt
```

When I try to run the code , I am getting following error .

```
./dsa
segmentation fault
```

**EDIT 1:**
I investigated further and found the reason for segmentation fault

```
#ifdef LTC_MPI
#include <stdarg.h>

int ltc_init_multi(void **a, ...)
{
...
...    
if (mp_init(cur) != CRYPT_OK) ---> This line causes segmentation fault
```

**Where am I making mistakes ? How to resolve this problem to run these programs successfully?**

I am using linux , gcc. Any help/link will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `-DUSE_TFM` to your `gcc` command.

Comment: when I use gcc -DUSE_TFM dsa_make_key_example.c -ltomcrypt -ltfm -o dsa , it gives compile time error. tfm_desc undeclared. Then I again rebuild libtomcrypt using CFLAGS="-DTFM_DESC -DUSE_TFM" EXTRALIBS=-ltfm make -f makefile.shared install , still I am getting same compile time error with -DUSE_TFM option with gcc. However, without -DUSE_TFM , gcc dsa_make_key_example.c -ltomcrypt -o dsa, no compile time error.

Comment: No compile time error with gcc -DLTM_LTM dsa_make_key_example.c -ltomcrypt -ltfm -o dsa, however runtime segmentation fault.

Comment: with gcc -DUSE_LTM dsa_make_key_example.c -ltomcrypt -ltommath -o dsa , it gives compile time error. ltm_desc undeclared.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a year or so since this was asked, but I have some component of an answer, and a workaround.

The reason `mp_init` fails is that the "math_descriptor" is uninitialized.  `mp_init` is a defined as

```
#define mp_init(a) ltc_mp.init(a)
```

where `ltc_mp` is a global struct (of type `ltc_math_descriptor`) that holds pointers to the math routines.

There are several implementations of the math routines available, and a user can choose which they want.  For whatever reason, there does not seem to be a default math implementation chosen for certain builds of libtomcrypt.  Thus, the `init` member of `ltc_mp` is null, and we get the SIGSEGV.

Here is a manual workaround:

You can make your desired `ltc_math_descriptor` struct available to your `main()` routine by `#define`ing one of

- LTM_DESC  -- built-in math lib
- TFM_DESC  -- an external fast math package
- GMP_DESC  -- presumably a GNU MultiPrecision implementation?

Before `#include <tomcrypt.h>` (or by using -D on the command-line).
Whichever you choose, a corresponding object will be declared:

```
extern const ltc_math_descriptor ltm_desc;
extern const ltc_math_descriptor tfm_desc;
extern const ltc_math_descriptor gmp_desc;
```

To use it, manually copy it to the global math descriptor:
E.g., in my case, for the local math imlpementation,

```
ltc_mp = ltm_desc;
```

Now libtomcrypt works.